# htmlspecialchars working with words not in english

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I want to prevent from reading special chars, e.g. if $txt="`<b>hello</b>`", I want to print "`<b>hello</b>"`, and not "**hello**" with bold.
So I added the line `$txt=htmlspecialchars($txt, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` . It solved the problem, but now if I type words that not in english, e.g. שלום (hebrew word), it give me `&#1513;&#1500;&#1493;&#1501;`. How do I solve it? This is my code:

```
$txt=$_POST['post_txt'];
$txt=htmlspecialchars($txt, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');/prevent xss
$txt=nl2br($txt);//make it with line breaks
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars('שלום', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` does not produce `&#1513;&#1500;&#1493;&#1501;`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if Hebrew is supported, but these sites might clear your problem up.  Also, htmlentities() should be used

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

http://www.techiecorner.com/129/php-how-to-convert-iso-character-htmlentities-to-utf-8/

Good luck!